# Can I catch fish in Valheim with a bow, spear, or by hand?

Tags: valheim

**Please, no spoilers.** My friend and I are very much enjoying the "explore & discover" aspects of this game and I don't want to ruin that. I accidentally spoiled myself already by trying to answer this by google search - so please, no (more) spoilers.

We already know that somewhere (near the world's edge, we think) there is a Trader. We have not found him (although last night we went on a trip to the edge of the world and promptly fell off, complete with our boat and all of our best gear). My earlier google search indicated that the Trader sells fishing rods.

So, my question... **is there any other way to hunt fish?** They don't seem to be susceptible to spears (thrown or stabbing) or to arrows (at least, not wooden or flint ones).

Again, **please** minimize spoilers - "yes" and "no" are perfect, although if I'm missing something with spear/bow fishing and it is possible, some guidance would be nice.

*: I don't consider "looking for fish that washed up on shore" to be "hunting".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to "hunt" fish.

As per the [Wiki](https://valheim.fandom.com/wiki/Fish): "Fish can be caught by hand or using a Fishing Rod and Fishing Bait, which are acquired via the trader.
You can obtain Raw Fish by grabbing the fish with [E]. When catching fish by hand, stand still in shallow water and they will slowly approach."

I don't know if this is what you mean by "washed up", but these are the only two ways.

Comment: I know the answer is a bit late but there is no accepted answer yet, and my answer omits the potential spoiler found in the second part of the previous answer, which I don't think is within the scope of what the asker was looking for. Might save anyone else looking for this from any additional spoilers.

Comment: I've never been successful using this "hand-catch" method, have you used it? I've certainly caught fish that have washed up onto shore, but I've never managed to get fish from the sea without the fishing rod. (We're 6 months later, my friend and I have finished all implemented bosses, so spoilers are no longer relevant for me, although I think I'd like to preserve the no-spoiler aspect of this question.)

Answer (score 0):

No.

> Once you reach the trader, you can buy a fishing pole, which will let you fish. The pole itself costs 350 gold, and you can also buy bait at a rate of 10 gold per 50 bait (each cast costs 1 bait).

You can also:

> Kill sea serpents for their meat, although it's not the generic fish meat, it is a special kind of meat. Harpoons can help with this, as well as a good bow and arrow.

Comment: I've definitely caught fish other ways.

Comment: @TimmyJim then feel free to add an answer or edit, because outside of finding them on the shore or using a fishing rod, I've not seen other ways.